# visual studio preview code plugin

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sublimetext2

When i was working in Sublime Text 2 i had for using good plugin (look at screen):[image]
I saw it in VS2013, but i haven't SP1 for this program. Could i get a name plugin for VS 2012 if it exists?

Answer (score 4):

For Vs2017 User, now we can setup at Tools->Options->Text Editor ->Scroll bars

[image]

Ref: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cdnstudents/2014/01/21/visual-studio-tips-and-tricks-enhanced-scroll-bar/

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same functionality in VS2012 using the [Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3a96a4dc-ba9c-4589-92c5-640e07332afd) extension.

The feature is under the enhanced scroll bar options - "map mode".